# Base64 string to pdf in groovy

Tags: pdf, groovy, base64, sap-cpi

I am new to groovy and to this forum.
I am using a middleware tool (SAP CPI) where I am getting a PDF in base64 string format. I need to send the PDF to another system.
This is what I did:

- Store the Base64 input in a string.
- Pass it through a Base64 Decoder (this is an inbuilt function)
- Use below code and pass the base64 string as an input to "body":

  ```
  import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  def Message processData(Message message){
  def body = message.getBody(String.class);
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  outputStream.write(body.getBytes())
  message.setBody(outputStream.toString())
  return message;
  }
  ```

What I get as an output looks something like below:

```
%PDF-1.7
%????
5 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<</Title(T....
```

and so on...

Now when I save this output as a pdf file, it is either blank or it says

> There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Note: Due to limitation of the middleware, I cannot create a whole project, but will rather have to use `processData()` function and can manipulate the string inside it. Thanks!

Comment: PDF is not a string. So problem appeared when you try to convert bytes to string outputStream.toString()

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have tried removing the toString() and using the binary output. I copy and paste the output in a notepad and save it as a pdf file. But when I open it, it still gives me the same error. Anything else I should try?

Comment: You can't copy paste binary data into notepad because notepad supports only text encodings..

Comment: did some more tweaking and turned out converting it to string was actually the problem. the code looks like:

import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
def Message processData(Message message) {
      def text = message.getBody(String)
       byte[] decoded = text.decodeBase64()
       def out = new String(decoded)
       message.setBody(out)
       return message
}

Now I am able to open the output as a pdf. Thank you!